# GraphQL Mutation Insert using Inner Query

Tags: graphql, graphql-mutation

How can I perform the following SQL Insert Query as a GraphQL Mutation Insert?

```
INSERT INTO User (id, name, user_type_id)
VALUES
(1, "Name", (SELECT id FROM UserType WHERE user_type="Guest"))
```

Provided that there is a `One to Many` relation from `UserType` table (id column) to `User` table (user_type_id column).

Comment: do you use a mapper like sequelize in your code or do you write raw queries. Also, graphql only transports the data to your server.

Comment: What I have is raw queries with payloads and send them for execution at the GraphQL endpoint. We already have a couple of Mutation Inserts, Upserts in our code. But, all of these GraphQL queries was for inserting to a specific table. But, what we are trying to achieve is to have a foreign key inserted in `User` table by using a where condition in `UserType` table. This works like a charm in an SQL query. But, unable to find any help on getting this work as a GraphQL insert.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout an ORM that work with your technology.
like 'sequelize' for example.